# Timer not working well in ADAPTER

Tags: java, android, timer

```
 public class ItemMemberAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ArrayList<Item> objects;
        Context context;
        Item itm;
        MyHolder holder;
        //timer
        long starttime = 0L;
        long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
        long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
        long updatedtime = 0L;
        int t = 1;
        int secs = 0;
        int mins = 0;
        int milliseconds = 0;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        //timer

        public ItemMemberAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
            this.context=context;
            this.objects=objects;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return objects.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Item getItem(int position) {
            return objects.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        class MyHolder{
            TextView m_time,l_time,name;
            Button s_btn,l_btn;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if(v==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_member_list_app,null);
                holder=new MyHolder();        
                holder.m_time= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                holder.l_time= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lap_time);
                holder.name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                holder.s_btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.strt_btn);
                holder.l_btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lap_btn);

                v.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder= (MyHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            itm=null;
            itm=getItem(position);
            final String nm = itm.getMember_name();
            final String t = itm.getTimerOne();

            holder.name.setText(nm);
            holder.m_time.setText(t);
            final Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - starttime;

                    updatedtime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

                    secs = (int) (updatedtime / 1000);
                    mins = secs / 60;
                    secs = secs % 60;
                    milliseconds = (int) (updatedtime % 1000);
                    String stime="" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds);
                    Log.d("timea", stime);
                    holder.l_time.setText(stime);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                }
            };
            holder.s_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Name : "+nm+" Time : "+t,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    starttime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 0);
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

    }
```

**This is my adapter, now issue is that when i am clicking on start Button then timer is starts and i can see Log but that LOG value is not set on textView...**

Answer (score 1):

Your code architecture is weird.

- Move your button onclick action outside the adapter
- Don't run `Runnable` inside adapter
- Measure time in activity, and pass data to adapter in array using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Adapter should only collect and display data in correct way. All data manipulation should be outside of the adapter. You are not getting values because you are not operating on UI thread in your case. However fixing it to work on UI thread in worst idea ever. Made refactor to your code with steps written above.

Comment: You can use ArrayAdapter or create custom Adapter with setData() method. All you need to replace dataset in adapter and refresh view.

Comment: it will replace entire listview data ,,..but what for only single view ?